# I want to save vim tag stack which caches project code tags when i exit vim

Tags: vim, tags, stack

how to save and restore vim tag stack?

I want to save vim tag stack which caches project code tags when i exit vim.

Then i can restore tag stack when i restore project code files buffer in vim.

I looked up vim session help document,there isn't anything about restore tag stack.

I think vim session can save anything other than tag stack.

Comment: AFAIK, the tag stack can't be saved across sessions. But the tag stack only records the tags you have jumped to, not *all* the tags of your project (unless you have jumped to all of them) so I'm not sure that's really what you want to save. It is empty by default and only populated when you jump to a tag so you can't manually or programmatically change it. Even if you manage to save the output of `:tags` (with `:redir`, for example), you probably won't be able to put it back into a fresh tag stack in a new session.

Answer (score 0):

The *viminfo* file persists various things, among them also the *jumplist*, but so far not the *tag jumps*. This information is lost as soon as you leave Vim. You can file an enhancement request on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php), arguing why this would be useful, or even better, submit a patch there that implements such.